# What is the significance of url-pattern in web.xml and how to configure servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml, url-pattern, servlet-mapping

I have manually configured `web.xml` for my application. Now, I'm facing issues while running my application. I'm trying to access my `servlet` from my `jsp` page. But, it is throwing error as `page not found`.

The servlets are placed under below folder location

```
<application folder>/WEB-INF/classes/<package>
```

So, what should be the entries for servlets in `url-pattern` and `servlet-mapping`. So that, `servlet` can be accessible through URL.

Comment: first read servlet specification and mappings. Refer to the answer given by @var_. If you again facing problem or exception paste the exception in question, Community will try to debug the problem.

Answer (score 74):

`url-pattern` is used in `web.xml` to map your `servlet` to specific URL. Please see below xml code, similar code you may find in your `web.xml` configuration file.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddPhotoServlet</servlet-name>  //servlet name
    <servlet-class>upload.AddPhotoServlet</servlet-class>  //servlet class
</servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddPhotoServlet</servlet-name>   //servlet name
    <url-pattern>/AddPhotoServlet</url-pattern>  //how it should appear
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you change `url-pattern` of `AddPhotoServlet` from `/AddPhotoServlet` to `/MyUrl`. Then, `AddPhotoServlet` servlet can be accessible by using `/MyUrl`. Good for the security reason, where you want to hide your actual page URL.

**Java Servlet `url-pattern` Specification:**

> 1. A string beginning with a **'/'** character and ending with a **'/*'**
>      suffix    is used for path mapping.
> 2. A string beginning with a **'*.'**
>      prefix is    used as an extension mapping.
> 3. A string containing only the **'/'**    character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this    case the servlet path
>      is the request URI minus the context path and    the path info is
>      null.
> 4. All other strings are used for exact matches    only.

Reference : [Java Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)

You may also read this [Basics of Java Servlet](https://apptech-solution.blogspot.com/2016/08/basics-of-java-servlet.html)

Comment: Just to add, if OP is using a Web Application servlet that supports Servlet 3.0, then there's no need to configure the servlet in the web.xml. There's a good explanation in [our Servlets Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: for the `/AddPhotoServlet` example -- would that Servlet be accessed by a link like `http://AddPhotoServlet.company.com/` ? Or would it be accessed by `http://company.com/AddPhotoServlet` ?

Answer (score 39):

Servlet-mapping has two child tags, url-pattern and servlet-name. url-pattern specifies the type of urls for which, the servlet given in servlet-name should be called. Be aware that, the container will use case-sensitive for string comparisons for servlet matching.

**First specification of** `url-pattern` a `web.xml` file for the server context on the servlet container at server .com  matches the pattern in `<url-pattern>/status/*</url-pattern>` as follows:

```
http://server.com/server/status/synopsis               = Matches
http://server.com/server/status/complete?date=today    = Matches
http://server.com/server/status                        = Matches
http://server.com/server/server1/status                = Does not match
```

**Second specification of** `url-pattern` A context located at the path /examples on the Agent at example.com matches the pattern in `<url-pattern>*.map</url-pattern>` as follows:

```
 http://server.com/server/US/Oregon/Portland.map    = Matches
 http://server.com/server/US/server/Seattle.map     = Matches
 http://server.com/server/Paris.France.map          = Matches
 http://server.com/server/US/Oregon/Portland.MAP    = Does not match, the extension is uppercase
 http://example.com/examples/interface/description/mail.mapi  =Does not match, the extension is mapi rather than map`
```

**Third specification of** `url-mapping`,A mapping that contains the pattern `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` matches a request if no other pattern matches. This is the default mapping. The servlet mapped to this pattern is called the default servlet.

The default mapping is often directed to the first page of an application. Explicitly providing a default mapping also ensures that malformed URL requests into the application return are handled by the application rather than returning an error.

The servlet-mapping element below maps the `server` servlet instance to the default mapping.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>server</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

For the context that contains this element, any request that is not handled by another mapping is forwarded to the `server` servlet.

And Most importantly we should Know about **Rule for URL path mapping**

1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request to the path of the servlet. A successful match selects the servlet.
2. The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This is done by stepping down the path tree a directory at a time, using the ’/’ character as a path separator. The longest match determines the servlet selected.
3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp), the servlet container will try to match a servlet that handles requests for the extension. An extension is defined as the part of the last segment after the last ’.’ character.
4. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the container will attempt to serve content appropriate for the resource requested. If a “default” servlet is defined for the application, it will be used.

Reference [URL Pattern](http://docs.roguewave.com/hydraexpress/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html)