# Using html forms in servlet code not working

Tags: java, html, forms, servlets

I'm trying to use forms in my servlet code like this;

```
 out.println("<FORM ACTION=\""+ BooksBought+"\"method = \"POST\">\n" +
         "<INPUT TYPE=\"SUBMIT\"\n "+
             "       VALUE=\"Update Order\">\n" +
             "</FORM>\n");
```

But I keep getting errors like BooksBought cannot be resolved to a variable. BooksBought is another servlet that works by itself so I know this is where the problem is. Please help.

web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>BooksBought</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>BooksBought</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-name>BooksBought</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>BooksBought</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Is BooksBought defined as a variable in the same method? Is it a global variable?  You probably need to post more code.

Comment: "errors **like** BooksBought cannot be..." Can you post the full stack trace and the surrounding code? Where did you declare `BooksBought`?

Comment: BooksBought is a servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If BooksBought is a servlet, not a variable, you should do more like:

```
   out.println("<FORM ACTION=\"BooksBought\" method=\"POST\">");
```

You also need to put a space between the " and method.  You could also use single quotes so you don't have to escape the quotes. Makes it easier to read.

```
   out.println("<FORM ACTION='BooksBought' method='POST'>");
```

If the servlet for this form is a level deeper than the one you are going to post to, you'll need to add a ../

```
   out.println("<FORM ACTION='../BooksBought' method='POST'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - it's not that magical.  That action needs to be the URL that maps to your BooksBought servlet.  Are you deploying these in a war?  Did you set up a web.xml?

Check out:

[What is url-pattern in web.xml and how to configure servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018215/what-is-url-pattern-in-web-xml-and-how-to-configure-servlet)

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets.htm

Comment: Also - all the cool kids are now using client-side templating instead of building static HTML on the server.  If you're interested, check out Handlebars, Mustache, Undescore templating, among others.

Comment: I'm working on eclipse, and I set up a web.xml. I also tried to use the URL that maps to the BooksBought servlet, but nothing works.

Comment: What container are you deploying to?  Are you sure that you don't have the url wrong?  Can I see the appropriate bits of your web.xml?

Comment: Make sure you put a / in front of your URL mapping if you're mapping to a path.  Also, your servlet-class should be fully qualified.  Are you seeing errors in the logfiles for your container when you attempt to startup or deploy?

Comment: If you used a URL string as your action parameter you would not get that error.  Please try again.