# url pattern for html file in web.xml

Tags: java, html, servlets, web.xml, url-pattern

we know how to set **url pattern** for **servlet** but I am unable to set **url pattern** for html in **web.xml**, can u help me to find solution, I googled but, can't able to get it, please find below for my problem.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>auth.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in above code I am setting **url pattern** for `**Login**` servlet class in **web.xml**, like wise can I able to set **url pattern** for html file in **web.xml** 
pls help to find solution thank you in advance

Comment: Hello, it's unclear what you are asking. Kindly be much more specific including things you have tried, for example regular expressions. Thanks! Hurry too, because this questions may get closed soon.

Comment: @Drakes i clearly mentioned in web.xml

Comment: I can sense that you are frustrated, so I'm going to bow out of this. Your answer is at this link. Best of luck. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018215/what-is-url-pattern-in-web-xml-and-how-to-configure-servlet

Answer (score 1):

URL pattern are for servlet and filters. 
For servlet

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet-name</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/< Pattern ></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

For Filter

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filter-Name</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/< Pattern ></url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Those are not for Html file. 
Infact there are no pattern configuration for JSPs too.

Comment: no you can't, inface HTML file doesent require any URL patter configuration. In tomcat HTML files can be accessed directly with their corresponding URLs.

Comment: I thought that we can set url pattern for html file, then how in the welcome file list alone they are setting index.html as startup page

Comment: Welcome file is a special case. It is configurable so that one can set welcome page other than default i.e index.html.   This way we can also set a servlet as a welcome page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to protect *.html files from direct access (by placing *.html files under WEB-INF) you can use a Servlet which would be only responsible for forwarding all such requests to intended html files.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HTMLServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.package.HTMLServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HTMLServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/somepath/*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Code in servlet class may look like this

```
...
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
  String requestedPath = //... code for getting requested HTML path
  request.getRequestDispatcher(requestedPath).forward(request, response);
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind to change your HTML page to JSP you can set url pattern for it like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Error</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/pages/error.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Error</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/error</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You don't need to change the page to a JSP. An HTML file will work just fine: `<jsp-file>/pages/error.html</jsp-file>`