# Why use *.jsf as servlet-mapping url pattern in web.xml

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, web.xml

The file `web.xml` allows the configuration of how the ending of JSF pages looks like. The default setting (`*.jsf`) is found in almost every JSF tutorial I found so far.

I personally prefer `*.xhtml` because in all my projects I had only files with the ending `.xhtml`.

What are the reasons of keeping to the `*.jsf` convention and why should I do it?
Are there any disadvantages when using another url-pattern, especially if it is the same as the actual fileending?
Or is it just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: It can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018215/what-is-url-pattern-in-web-xml-and-how-to-configure-servlet

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why ? Using .xhtml instead of .jsf is more secure since you do not stand the chance of someone seeing the raw xhtml (see links in the 'duplicate')

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914660/what-is-the-difference-between-creating-jsf-pages-with-jsp-or-xhtml-or-jsf-ex is what answered my question. Thanks!