# using servlets name and servlets-url in web.xml in java eclipse

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

i want to know what should i put inside Servletname tag and url path in servlet-mapping in web.xml in eclipse.i tried googling it but i didnt find answer. Please suggest me in this, i am creating rest services in Java.

```
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>FirstWebserviceApplication</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>com.restservice.jersey</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>FirstWebserviceApplication</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018215/what-is-url-pattern-in-web-xml-and-how-to-configure-servlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Element : servlet-name**
The servlet-name element contains the canonical name of the 
 servlet. Each servlet name is unique within the web application. 
 Used in: filter-mapping, servlet, servlet-mapping

**Element : url-pattern**
The url-pattern element contains the url pattern of the mapping. This is how you want your servlet class to be accessed. if you put `/hello` then your servlet will invoke when user access `http://yourdomain/yourappname/hello`

Comment: http://javapapers.com/java/java-restful-web-services-with-json-and-jersey/ i have followed this link to create rest services ,so i dont know much about this as this is my first work in eclipse.where could i find servlet-name and url-pattern ?is it just hard coding or where could i find it

Answer (score 0):

> You define servlets as a part of a Web application in several entries in the J2EE standard Web Application deployment descriptor, web.xml. The web.xml file is located in the WEB-INF directory of your Web application.

The first entry, under the root servlet element in web.xml, **defines a name for the servlet** and **specifies the compiled class** that executes the servlet. (Or, instead of specifying a servlet class, you can specify a JSP.) The servlet element also contains definitions for initialization attributes and security roles for the servlet.

The second entry in web.xml, under the servlet-mapping element, **defines the URL pattern** that calls this servlet.

> NOTE : - You can give servlet a name as per your convenience and naming convention, you need only to make sure servlet name is unique within the web application

to answer your question if you are creating REST servies using jersey put web.xml contents as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>JSON RESTful Services</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>JSON RESTful Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.javapapers.webservices.rest.jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JSON RESTful Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

you can also check this post http://www.tutorialsdesk.com/2014/09/jersey-restful-webservices-tutorial.html Jersey RESTful Webservices example

Comment: http://javapapers.com/java/java-restful-web-services-with-json-and-jersey/ i have followed this link to create rest services ,so i dont know much about this as this is my first work in eclipse.where could i find servlet-name and url-pattern

Comment: @allDroid The web.xml file is located in the WEB-INF directory of your Web application.

Comment: yes i have found web.xml page but i dont know what to put in servlet-name and url-pattern.Where should i find them ?or is it hard coding?

Comment: in above URL contents of web.xml are also given serach for web.xml

Comment: can u give me a example for this i didnt get what u explained