# Servlet in Java using Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

Below are the warnings and error when i run my java file it contains only the basic override methods of servlet interface. I have configured tomcat in eclipse.

```
 Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:LalitCheck' did not find a matching property.
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          Dec 7 2015 13:07:11 UTC
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server number:         7.0.67.0
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            6.1
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          x86
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Lalit\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Lalit\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Lalit\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Users\Lalit\Downloads\eclipse-jee-kepler-sr1-win32\eclipse;;.
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8111"]
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8222"]
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 1087 ms
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:26 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
    INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [141] milliseconds.
    Feb 18, 2016 12:14:26 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
    INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Lalit\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\LalitCheck\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Feb 18, 2016 12:14:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/LalitCheck]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/LalitCheck]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> Hello in servlet mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3388)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3363)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1438)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1357)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5479)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Feb 18, 2016 12:14:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Feb 18, 2016 12:14:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8333]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Feb 18, 2016 12:14:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8111"]
Feb 18, 2016 12:14:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8222"]
Feb 18, 2016 12:14:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Feb 18, 2016 12:14:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8111"]
Feb 18, 2016 12:14:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8222"]
```

Comment: you could add your code

Comment: I think to take the port 8080 and the other program (for example skype) is listening on his

Comment: please post your code and web.xml relevant parts

Answer (score 1):

The reason is an incorrect `<url-pattern>` in the `web.xml`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> Hello in servlet mapping
```

[What is url-pattern in web.xml and how to configure servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018215/what-is-url-pattern-in-web-xml-and-how-to-configure-servlet)