# Java web App how to map filter for more url

Tags: java, filter

I have own filter and I want add this filter to my url.

**Url are:**

```
admin_menu
admin_users
admin_banana
admin_orange
```

My mapping:

```
sce.getServletContext().addFilter("adminFilter1", adminGuar).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/admin_menu");

sce.getServletContext().addFilter("adminFilter2", adminGuar).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/admin_users");

sce.getServletContext().addFilter("adminFilter3", adminGuar).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/admin_banana");

sce.getServletContext().addFilter("adminFilter4", adminGuar).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/admin_orange");
```

Is there any better way how to map filter? I mean using one command.

I try map url **/admin_*** (but it not working !):

```
sce.getServletContext().addFilter("adminFilter", adminGuar).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/admin_*");
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards can only be used for [extension mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14018272/3215527).

But the last parameter of method `FilterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns` is a var arg so you can write a little bit shorter

```
sce.getServletContext().addFilter("adminFilter", adminGuar).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, 
    "/admin_menu", "/admin_users", "/admin_banana", "/admin_orange");
```

Additionally the current URL schema cries out for the following redesign:

```
/admin/menu
/admin/users
/admin/banana
/admin/orange
```

which then allows

```
 sce.getServletContext().addFilter("adminFilter", adminGuar)
    .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/admin/*");
```