# swagger2 not working with Spring REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, swagger-2.0

I have a spring application whose web.xml looks like below:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Inside my `app-servlet.xml` I have the below config entry:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.rest.apidoc" />
```

I have my `SwaggerConfig` inside the `com.rest.apidoc` directory

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Now when I try to run the app `http://domain:port/app/service/api-docs`, I get the error on my console `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/service/api-docs] in DispatcherServlet with name 'app'`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is few things that may go wrong:

1. you don't register appropriate resource handlers. [example](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-security-rest/src/main/java/org/baeldung/spring/WebConfig.java)
2. you may hit the wrong url. "app" is only a servlet name, doesn't need to appear in url. [servlet-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018215/what-is-url-pattern-in-web-xml-and-how-to-configure-servlet)
3. if you've registered resource handlers correctly and included springfox-swagger-ui dependency in your project, you need to request "http://domain:port/service/swagger-ui.html" to see API documented with swagger.

Refer to the following project to check whether you've configured your application correctly: [Spring Security for REST Example Project](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-rest)