# How to use ConstraintMapping to exclude a specific path in jetty?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a Constraint/ConstraintMapping that enables authentication. However, I need to exclude exactly one path from it, where authentication is not needed (and only for GET requests).

I created a constraint mapping with no constraint:

```
    ConstraintMapping exclude = new ConstraintMapping();
    exclude.setPathSpec("/items/{id}/list");
    exclude.setMethod("GET");
```

The questions I have regarding this is:

- How can I add a pathSpec where there is an {id} parameter? I believe using **setPathSpec("/items/{id}/list")** wouldn't work.
- If I add the method GET, will it be only enabled for GET requests to that endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

`ConstraintMapping` is a servlet concept.

The PathSpec only supports `url-pattern` rules from the servlet spec.

Your declaration of `/items/{id}/list` looks like a URI Template based path spec, which is unsupported by the Servlet spec.

See past answer on what the servlet url-pattern rules are ...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14018272/775715